# Copy SVG image stored as XML string to Windows clipboard as image/svg+xml MIME type

Tags: c#, windows, svg, clipboard

I have an SVG image stored as a .net XML `string`. If I write that string to a file, I can load it into SVG editors without any trouble, so I know its contents are good. But what I want to do is place it in the Windows clipboard as the `image/svg+xml` MIME type. I've tried the following:

```
string svg = GetSvg();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svg);

Clipboard.SetData("image/svg+xml", svg); // idea 1
Clipboard.SetData("image/svg+xml", bytes); // idea 2
```

Based on my clipboard viewer tool, both techniques produce (almost) the same result--The XML text is there as expected under image/svg+xml, but it is prefixed with 43 bytes that are definitely not present in `svg` or `bytes`:

[image: Clipboard viewer]

These bytes differ slightly depending on whether I write the text as a string or a byte array, so I suspect they are some sort of description of the data format. However, no SVG editor I have will accept the result for pasting. Is there more I need to do?

Comment: Have you looked into `bytes` array in debugger? Are these bytes there, in the beginning of array?

Comment: @Dennis, I have, and they are not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those extra bytes looked an awful lot like a serialization header, so I hunted around and eventually found this [note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx) in the MSDN documentation for the `Clipboard` class (bolding mine):

> An object must be serializable for it to be put on the Clipboard. If
>   you pass a non-serializable object to a Clipboard method, the method
>   will fail without throwing an exception. See
>   System.Runtime.Serialization for more information on serialization. **If
>   your target application requires a very specific data format, the
>   headers added to the data in the serialization process may prevent the
>   application from recognizing your data. To preserve your data format,
>   add your data as a Byte array to a MemoryStream and pass the
>   MemoryStream to the SetData method**.

That suggested an obvious course of action:

```
string svg = GetSvg();
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svg);
MemorySteam stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Clipboard.SetData("image/svg+xml", stream);
```

That worked! Further, I can confirm that `DataObject.SetData()` will also accept a `MemoryStream` in case you are looking to push the image to the clipboard in both svg and bitmap form at the same time.

Comment: Is there a way to do a similar thing in python? i.e. copy svg xml string to clipboard as "image/svg+xml" MIME data?

Comment: @Alex I presume so, but I couldn't tell you how.